# Add selector to button on UIScrollView views added dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have an UIScrollView with n views added dynamically from metadata stored by archiving. I have a PressGesture to make **wobble** animation (like iOS deleting apps way) and i want to add a button to every subview on the ScrollView for deleting it from the ScrollView and from files.

My problem is for adding the target to the buttons. When they are pressed, the selector (on the UIViewController  parent of the UIScrollView) are not called.

How can I get this done? Any other approach is suggested?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would be easier for us to help if you could provide the code where you are creating the button and are trying to set the target and selector

Answer (score 1):

When you animate the view it stops responding to user input. And if your button is located inside animated view, it will definitely not call the selector.

The solution would be to wrap your wobbling view into a transparent superview and then place Delete button inside that superview. If you need your button to be also "wobbling" then you need to put an image that represents button inside your wobbling view. And inside wrapper put a transparent Custom button, that will in fact react on user tap.